# Can you make a Neural Network drunk or high?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, human-like

We know that the human brain can become sozzled by various substances that are released into the brain, but can you make an artificial neural network drunk or high? For example on a RL Agent that still does the task somewhat but behaves silly?

Comment: In a way, the original Deep Dream was kinda like this - a network designed for a serious task modified to take it to absurdity

Comment: How do you define silliness?  For example, making a NN behave randomly (e.g., making random predictions independent of the input), is pretty trivial.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve "abrupt" behavior we can try to **multiply** the network weights by some constant > 1 (10 or 100 for example, depends on wanted degree).
If we want sillier behavior - we can **dropout/zero** some weights portion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).